# how to print pdf using javax printing?

Tags: java, printing

why is the following code **not printing anything**? Please help. I tried changing doc flavour, print request attributes. its a simple java file that print a pdf file. if you want to see the pdf, here is a [link to the repo](https://bitbucket.org/basithkunimal/java_printing). I've installed all drivers and can print the same pdf file using other programs like reader and firefox.

```
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class PrintPdf {

  static String label = "HP DeskJet 5810 series"; // change this to your printer name

  public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
  {
    // DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF; // not working
    // DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE; // not working
    // DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE; // not working
    DocFlavor flavor = new DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM("application/octet-stream");
    PrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    // attr.add(Sides.DUPLEX); // not working
    // attr.add(MediaSize.ISO.A4); // not working
    PrintService[] ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, attr);
    if (ps.length == 0) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("No Printer found");
    }
    System.out.println("Available printers: " + Arrays.asList(ps));

    PrintService myService = null;
    for (PrintService printService : ps) {
      if (printService.getName().equals(label)) {
          myService = printService;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (myService == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Printer not found");
    }

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./example.pdf");
    Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);
    DocPrintJob printJob = myService.createPrintJob();
    printJob.print(pdfDoc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
    fis.close();
  }
}
```

here is what happens, after a few seconds of waiting the `Java Printing` job disappears from the queue without printing anything

[image]

Comment: Perhaps because the printer driver doesn't know how to handle a pdf

Comment: i've installed the drivers. and the pdf can be printed from other programs

Comment: what other programs?

Comment: firefox. adobe reader etc.

Comment: Well of course: these programs print PDFs themselves, not the driver.

Comment: You may consider using something like pdfbox: https://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: ok i'll check it out. thanks

Comment: Have you tried not closing fis? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/DocPrintJob.html says "Print service implementors should close any print data streams" which implies you do not need to do it. Maybe the printing works asynchronously and cannot read any more data after you close the stream?

Comment: hi @FrankLauterwald, i tried it and its not working. thanks for the help

Comment: @bazi You're welcome. Glad it worked